# Is there any tutorial about adding radiobutton, list view and check box adding to firebase website?

Tags: checkbox

```
var year = year.value;
```

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at lagreURL (index.js:100)
    at

Comment: Where is your `year` value defined. Try `console.log(year);` on the line before to help you debug.

Comment: var year = document.getElementById("YearLevel");                                   
var year = year.value;                                  firebase.database().ref('tutors/' + student).set({
                 
   yearlevel: year
            });
   }